# Markdown example in helpcenter is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The [helpcenter description of markdown formatting of inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) contains the following text...

You can use a `<div>`for this with `display: inline-block;`

It then explains that this will be displayed as

```
You can use a <div for this with <display: inline-block; set.
```

But that's not quite right as the close angle bracket is missing from the div and an additional spurious open angle bracket is present before the word display.

Comment: There's also a space missing in the code block two lines above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both items have been fixed now.